# Incorrect representation of the string in csv file

Tags: windows, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I'm on Win7, Python2.7.

Have the string.
**Original view**:

> A. P. Møller Mærsk

UTF-8:

```
s = 'A. P. M\xc3\xb8ller M\xc3\xa6rsk'
```

I need to write it in csv.
Try this:

```
with open('14.09 Anbefalte aksjer.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([s])
```

**Got this:**

> A. P. MГёller MГ¦rsk

Try to use UnicodeWriter:

```
class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

s = 'A. P. M\xc3\xb8ller M\xc3\xa6rsk'.decode('utf8')
with open('14.09 Anbefalte aksjer.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = UnicodeWriter(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([s])
```

**And got again:**

> A. P. MГёller MГ¦rsk

Try unicodecsv:

**Again:**

> A. P. MГёller MГ¦rsk

What's wrong? How can I write it right?

Comment: What are you opening your CSV file with? Excel is legendary bad at handling Unicode/UTF-8-encoded CSV data, when you open files via a simple double click. Try the program’s Import dialog, I think there you can chose what character encoding should be assumed. If that doesn’t work, try LibreOffice’s/OpenOffice’s Calc, that offers options as well. Or at least open it in NotePad++, and see if that gets the encoding right.

Comment: Thank you, CBroe. I've made it by changing excel encoding.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is a mojibake: bytes that represent a Unicode text encoded in one character encoding are shown in another (incompatible) character encoding.

If `''.decode('utf8')` doesn't raise `AttributeError` then it means that you are not on Python 3 (despite what you question says). On Python 2, `csv` doesn't support Unicode directly, you have to encode manually:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

text = "A. P. Møller Mærsk"
with open('14.09 Anbefalte aksjer.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Both `UnicodeWriter` and `unicodecsv` module should work as well if `text` contains uncorrupted data.

Answer (score 0):

Windows assumes the default Window locale's encoding with tools like Notepad or Excel, so for UTF-8 a byte order mark (BOM, U+FEFF) must be encoded at the start of the file.  Python provides an encoding for this, `utf-8-sig`.  Note also by using `#coding:utf8` and saving your source file in UTF-8, you can declare your string directly as a Unicode string.  Finally, files for use with the `csv` module should be opened as `wb` on Python 2.7 or you will see problems writing newlines on Windows.

```
#coding:utf8
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
import codecs

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    # Use utf-8-sig encoding here.
    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8-sig", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

s = u'A. P. Møller Mærsk' # declare as Unicode string.
with open('14.09 Anbefalte aksjer.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = UnicodeWriter(csvfile)
    writer.writerow([s])
```

Output:

```
A. P. Møller Mærsk
```